# Remove Char11 from XML File

Tags: java, xml

DirecTV SWM-32 Satellite Multiswitch 4x8 Channel SWiM SWM32R1 w/ 20V & 24V Power

After Power there is an upside down question mark that is showing as Char11 and is causing SAP to throw an Error on import.  We have been unable to remove the Char11 from the source.  Is there anyway to Prefilter the XML to Remove Illegal Chars?

I would love a command line script that could be run prior to the import.

Comment: the XML TAGs were removed from the post.

Answer (score 0):

If `str` is your source string, try:

```
str = str.replace("\u000B", "");
```